# Pep8 E501: line too long error

Tags: python, twitter, pep8

I get the error `E501: line too long` from this code:

```
header, response = client.request('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses   /user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&screen_name='+username+'&count=1')
```

but if I write this way or another way:

```
    header, response = client.request('\
       https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.\
           json?include_entities=true&screen_name='+username+'&count=1')
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Unsupported URL             https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline            .json?include_entities=true&screen_name=username&count=1 ().
```

or I get this error:

```
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

So please tell me, how can I pass this error?

Comment: Instead of ending lines with backslashes, try concatenating strings across multiple lines.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The whitespaces at the beginning of the lines become part of your string if you break it like this.

Try this:

```
header, response = client.request(
   'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.'
   'json?include_entities=true&screen_name=' + username + '&count=1')
```

The strings will [automatically be concatenated](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation).

Answer (score 6):

You could also go to into the code analysis and ignore that kind or error/warning. I am using eclipse and Pydev.

```
Windows > Preferences > Pydev > Editor > Code Analysis > pycodestyle.py (pep8)

then add to arguments : --ignore=E501
```

Restart Eclipse and it should be fine for this warning.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a appropriate answer, since it's implied that E501 is a wanted rule. Of course it can be disabled but Pep8 E501 exists for a reason. Not that anybody has to abide by it unless required to by their job or such.

Answer (score 1):

You could build the string on multiple lines:

```
st='https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?'
st=st+'include_entities=true&screen_name='+username+'&count=1'

header, response = client.request(st)
```

Comment: Automatic string concatenation is preferred, in general, over the build string pattern. It shouldn't impact performance in this case, but Python strings are immutable, so doing `strA = 'foo'; strA += 'bar'` will require around double the memory and half the speed versus `strA = 'foo'\n'bar'`. General guideline though, not hard and fast rule.