# python giving a E501: line too long error

Tags: python, compiler-errors

While trying to input my API key python is giving me a line too long code

```
E501: line too long
```

What I have is

```
notifications_client = NotificationsAPIClient(aaaaaaa_aaaaaaaa-11aa1a1a-aa11-111a-aaaa-11111aaa1a1a-aa11a1a1-0aa1-11a1-1111-1aa111a0a111)
```

For obvious reasons I have changed the API key to have only a's 1's and 0's but how can I break up this line of code so I no longer get this error?

Comment: Python itself doesn't produce that sort of error.  It looks as if you are using some sort of linter or style checker?

Comment: I am currently using Codenvy to begin writing the API integration with python but its been a nightmare thus far. Within the same line of code it is also giving me a syntax error which im not understanding either

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pep8 E501: line too long error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685184/pep8-e501-line-too-long-error)

Answer (score 10):

E501 is a linter error, not a Python interpreter error. Your code, in theory, should work just fine. If you want to prevent this error, simply break the value up (assuming it's a string ... you don't make that clear):

```
my_key = ('aaaaaaa_aaaaaaaa-11aa1a1a-aa11-111a-aaaa-'
          '11111aaa1a1a-aa11a1a1-0aa1-11a1-1111-'
          '1aa111a0a111')
notifications_client = NotificationsAPIClient(my_key)
```

Answer (score 3):

E501 is not a python error, rather than a PEP8 error. Meaning your line is longer than 80 chars (in your case it's 137 chars long).

Your editor or runtime are verifying that your code is correct by PEP8 rules and that's why you are getting this "error". Your Python code has actually no errors at all.

If you want your code to be PEP8 compliant I suggest:

1. Extract the API key to a local variable.
2. If it's still too long you can break up the string into multiple lines

Here is an example:

```
API_KEY = 'aaaaaaa_aaaaaaaa-11aa1a1a-aa11-111a' \ 
          '-aaaa-11111aaa1a1a-aa11a1a1-0aa1-' \
          '11a1-1111-1aa111a0a111'
notifications_client = NotificationsAPIClient(API_KEY)
```

Comment: some linters will complain about using backslash usage here

Answer (score 0):

Use \ to break your line. Like;
notifications_client = NotificationsAPIClient(aaaaaaa_aaaaaaaa-11aa1a1a-\
aa11-111a-aaaa-11111aaa1a1a-\
aa11a1a1-0aa1-11a1-1111-1aa111a0a111)

Answer (score -1):

Option which doesn't involved breaking the string literal:

```
notifications_client = NotificationsAPIClient(
    "kkkkkkkkkkkkkeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
)
```

So long as your key is <73 (minus scope indentation) characters long. If not, you'll have to split it.