# E501 line too long (144 > 79 characters)

Tags: python, scrapy

```
subprocess.check_output(['scrapy', 'crawl', 'mySpider', '-a', f'url={self.url}', '-a', f'nbrPage={self.pages}', '-o', 'test.json'])  # noqa
```

I splitted the line into multiple ones and I got invalid syntax:

```
subprocess.check_output(['scrapy', 'crawl', 'mySpider',
                         '-a', f'url={self.url}', '-a', f'nbrPage={self.pages}', '-o', 'test.json'])
```

How can I fix this please?

------------------------ Edit2 ------------------------

The full code:

```
import scrapy
import subprocess
import json
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

class ClassSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name        = 'mySpider'
    #pages      = 0
    news        = []

    def __init__(self, url, nbrPage):
        self.pages      = nbrPage
        self.start_urls = url

    def parse(self):
        ...

    def run(self):
        command_args = [
            'scrapy',
            'crawl',
            'mySpider',
            '-a',
            f'url={self.url}',  #I have this error: invalid syntax pyflakes
            '-a',
            f'nbrPage={self.pages}',
            '-o',
            'test.json'
        ]
        subprocess.check_output(command_args)
        return self.news

app = Flask(__name__)
data = []

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def getNews():
    mySpiderClass = ClassSpider(request.json['url'], 2)

    data.append(mySpider.run())
    return jsonify({'data': data})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

At the line where I added the comment, I have a highlight which says that I have invalid syntax pyflakes.

------------------------ Edit3 ------------------------

The result of pip freeze:

```
appdirs==1.4.4
applicationinsights==0.11.9
asgiref==3.2.7
astroid==2.4.1
astunparse==1.6.3
autopep8==1.5.3
backcall==0.1.0
backports.csv==1.0.7
bleach==3.1.5
cachetools==4.1.0
certifi==2020.4.5.1
chardet==3.0.4
cli-helpers==0.2.3
Click==7.0
configobj==5.0.6
decorator==4.4.2
distlib==0.3.0
Django==3.0.6
enum34==1.1.10
filelock==3.0.12
flake8==3.8.2
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-PyMongo==2.3.0
future==0.18.2
gast==0.3.3
google-api-core==1.17.0
google-api-python-client==1.9.1
google-auth==1.16.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.1
google-cloud-bigquery==1.24.0
google-cloud-core==1.3.0
google-cloud-datastore==1.12.0
google-cloud-language==1.3.0
google-cloud-logging==1.15.0
google-cloud-spanner==1.17.0
google-cloud-storage==1.28.1
google-cloud-translate==2.0.1
google-cloud-videointelligence==1.14.0
google-cloud-vision==1.0.0
google-pasta==0.2.0
google-resumable-media==0.5.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.51.0
grpc-google-iam-v1==0.12.3
grpcio==1.29.0
h5py==2.10.0
httplib2==0.18.1
humanize==2.4.0
idna==2.9
importlib-metadata==1.6.0
ipython==7.15.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
isort==4.3.21
itsdangerous==1.1.0
jedi==0.17.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
Markdown==3.2.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
mccabe==0.6.1
mssql-cli==1.0.0
mypy==0.770
mypy-extensions==0.4.3
numpy==1.18.4
oauth2client==4.1.3
oauthlib==3.1.0
opt-einsum==3.2.1
packaging==20.4
parso==0.7.0
pexpect==4.8.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
pluggy==0.13.1
prompt-toolkit==3.0.5
protobuf==3.12.2
psycopg2==2.8.5
ptyprocess==0.6.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycodestyle==2.6.0
pydocstyle==5.0.2
pyflakes==2.2.0
Pygments==2.6.1
pylint==2.5.2
pyls-mypy==0.1.8
pymongo==3.10.1
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-jsonrpc-server==0.3.4
python-language-server==0.33.0
pytz==2020.1
PyYAML==5.3.1
requests==2.23.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
rope==0.17.0
rsa==4.0
scipy==1.4.1
six==1.15.0
snowballstemmer==2.0.0
sqlparse==0.2.4
tensorboard==2.2.2
tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.6.0.post3
tensorflow==2.2.0
tensorflow-estimator==2.2.0
termcolor==1.1.0
terminaltables==3.1.0
toml==0.10.1
traitlets==4.3.3
typed-ast==1.4.1
typing-extensions==3.7.4.2
ujson==1.35
uritemplate==3.0.1
urllib3==1.25.9
virtualenv==20.0.21
wcwidth==0.2.3
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==1.0.1
wrapt==1.12.1
yapf==0.30.0
zipp==3.1.0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pep8 E501: line too long error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685184/pep8-e501-line-too-long-error)

Comment: Take a look at [black](https://pypi.org/project/black/), it is a code formatter.

Comment: Hi Ch3steR, no the post's not working for me, I'll check black recommandation, Thank you

Comment: @MedADDOU please provdes a pip freeze of your env, and add the full stacktrace from the console when you run it

Comment: Are you running this in python3 right? f-string is python3 only feature

Comment: @Reznik I just added the reuslt of pip freeze. Yes the code is running on python37

Comment: @MedADDOU maybe there is a bug with pyflakes? try to uninstall it

Answer (score 0):

I can't really spot the mistake in what you have written, but a good practice to avoid those kind of invalid sytnax such as indent error is to split things up:

```py
command_args = [
    'scrapy',
    'crawl',
    'mySpider',
    '-a',
    f'url={self.url}',
    '-a',
    f'nbrPage={self.pages}',
    '-o',
    'test.json'
]
subprocess.check_output(command_args)
```

It much more clear and if you work with git and you change one argument it will be much easier to spot the difference

also much more readable and i think it will be much more clear to debug it that way

Comment: I agree with you, however I tried your proposal but it doesn't work. I got invalid syntax

Comment: @MedADDOU in what line?

Comment: This line f"url={self.url}",

Comment: @MedADDOU can you add the full stacktrace?

Comment: I think the problem comes from the fact that we add an argument to the list with f which is outside the double ''
`command_args = [
'scrapy',
'crawl',
'mySpider',
'-a',
f'url={self.url}',
'-a',
f'nbrPage={self.pages}',
'-o',
'test.json'
]
`
As you can see f'url={self.url}', with f which must be in ''
What do you think?

Comment: @MedADDOU add the full code to your post and also the full stacktrace

Comment: I just edited the post, but I don't have the stacktrace, I don't know how to have it in app engine!!